# Problems generating a signature with php

Tags: php, api, md5

Having a little problem with an API that's out there and before I admit that it's broken and i'm not - figured someone might see what i'm doing wrong.

This is what they are asking for as part of the url - a signature that is formed by this:
hex-encoded MD5(key + secret + timestamp)

And this is what i'm giving them that's failing:

```
$key = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$secret = 'DeMxxxxxxxxxw';
$timestamped = $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'];
$signature = md5($key + $secret + $timestamped);
```

So am I doing something wrong or are they not playing with me well?

Comment: Have you considered a third possibility: the key, secret or timestamp are incorrect?

Comment: md5's are very specific, which is their whole purpose. Someone (you? the api?) wants to check their value against your MD5 to see if they match. So my guess is, you either need to store the time somewhere so you can reference it later, or you need to use a timestamp that you got from the API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you want to use `.` (concatenation) instead of `+` (sum)

```
$signature = md5($key . $secret . $timestamped);
```

Comment: Awesome - got a response.  Thanks for pointing out the obvious :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean to concatenate the strings with `.` instead of add numerically with `+`.

`$signature = md5($key . $secret . $timestamped);`

Answer (score 1):

the concatenation operator in PHP is '.', not '+'

Answer (score 1):

Do you really want to add these together or to you want to concatenate them?

```
// Adding
$signature = md5($key + $secret + $timestamped);
// Concatenating
$signature = md5($key . $secret . $timestamped);
```